# What word means "the ability to read more than one form of writing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a person can speak and understand two languages, he is *bilingual*. How would you describe a person who can read and write in two languages with very different forms of writing, such as Chinese and English, or Sanskrit and Korean, or what have you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Biliterate* is 
[defined as](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/biliterate):

1. (adj) able to read and write in two languages.
2. (noun) a person who is biliterate.

However, it appears that *multiliteracy* has morphed into a whole other meaning having to do with [multimodal ways of communicating.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiliteracy)

Comment: It appears "polyliterate" is a way of extending literacy over more than two languages.

Comment: @KitGrose: that's odd; it breaks the analogy with *bilingual/multilingual*. Due to the traditional idea that it's best to match Latin roots with other Latin roots, *polyliterate* seems a bit oddly formed. Then again, Latin and Greek roots are in practice often mixed (as seen by the use of *monolingual*, *monocultural* etc. rather than *unilingual, unicultural*). Anyway, this [talk page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Multiliteracy) mentions *pluriliterate* as an another term for "literate in multiple languages."

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there is a single word to describe this ability. But you can use the word **literate** with the desired languages in order to denote someone's ability to read and write the languages in question. So you can say that someone is *Chinese and English literate*, for example.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was essentially the same as yours, but I would still prefer the form *literate in Chinese and English*.

Comment: @Danielδ: I think it boils down to stylistic preferences. I love this ability of the English language to allow you to say that you are able to read and write a language in just two words. The definition of succinctness.

Comment: Well, what I was looking for is a general term. If I know someone can read and write in two languages, but I don't know what those languages are, I don't see how I can use this expression.