# A word for when you only understand a language in its written form

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word to express when you only understand the written form of a language?

For instance: I can read Portuguese, but I can't understand it when it's spoken to me.

Comment: @JLG: "able to read and write" is too strong. I can read Portuguese, but I can't write in it.

Comment: Jsuissa: Can you write, as well as read, Portuguese?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What word means "the ability to read more than one form of writing"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61769/what-word-means-the-ability-to-read-more-than-one-form-of-writing)

Comment: In my case no -- but that's interesting, did you have a certain word in mind?

Comment: *Literate,* which means the ability to read and write. You could say you are proficient in reading Portuguese. Linguists talk about *reading proficiency*, especially with regard to a second language. http://www.ling.lancs.ac.uk/activities/891/

Comment: "I can read Portuguese, but I can't understand it when it's spoken to me." Is he Portuguese or of others country?

Comment: Try listening to Brazilian instead of Portuguese; you’ll find it much easier to understand despite being virtually identical. For one thing, Brazilian is more syllable-timed and Portuguese is more of a stress-timed language. For another, Portuguese has more vowel sounds than Brazilian does (something like 29 phonemically distinct oral and nasal monopthongs, dipthongs, and tripthongs), but uses fewer in a phrase because of many silent or nearly silent vowels. Spoken Portuguese sounds Slavic (if you don’t know Slavic); spoken Brazilian is much closer to Spanish.

Comment: Just to answer an earlier comment -- I'm American so it's not my native language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you want a word to describe a non-native or learner of the language. For Europeans learning other European languages (where the writing is in the Roman or Cyrillic alphabet and learning to read is trivial in comparison to speak and listen), you would say that a person has

> **having reading proficiency**

in the language. For a single word adjective, I don't think there's a wod for any particular ability like 'speakability' or 'readability' (that means what you want it to mean).

For languages where the accepted writing system takes much more study like Chinese or Japanese, most people learn those languages academically where the proficiency in both go at about the same rate (it's almost like learning two different languages at the same time, spoken and written).

For the other side, for native speakers, there is only the issue of whether they can read their own language and for that

> **literate**

captures the idea.

'Literate' could also work for the non-native learner, but even though intended for only the reading skill, might be misunderstood for 'well-educated' in the language, meaning both able to read -and- speak well.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to coin a new term. I suggest

```
solumliterate - literacy without other language ability
```

Similarly, for someone with speaking ability but not literacy you could say

```
solumlingual - speaking ability without literacy
```

which is better than "illiterate" which is a pejorative these days.
You could also say

```
solumnumerate - numeracy without literacy or spoken linguistic ability
```

as in "until recently computers were solumnumerate".

The "solum" is from the Latin "solum" when used as "only" or "merely"

Comment: I thought about *semiliterate* or *half-literate*, but they both appear to be somewhat derogatory, with the connotation of being uneducated. I don't think most people would understand your prefix. And you still have the problem of *literate* referring to both reading and writing. The OP stated that he doesn't have the speaking/listening ability, so *lingual* doesn't really work as an answer to this question.

Comment: Edited answer to address comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about *non-aurally fluent*?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=literate&i=2&h=01000#c), there is no such term.

Comment: The entry you linked says that adjective *literate* means "able to read and write".  It does not say there is no term for being able to understand only the written form of a language.

Comment: But it shows all the sister terms for literate. If there were a word, it should be there.