# how to describe a person capable of reading and writing in more than one language

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

what would describe the person who able to read and write in more than one language. Is there any other descriptive word than "Bilingual"?

Comment: A *polyglot*? A *linguist* (though that sense has been almost completely obscured by the "academic who studies languages" sense).

Comment: Perhaps multilingual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun for this is "[polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglotism)".

"Polyglotism or polyglottism is the ability to master, or the state of having mastered, multiple languages."

"[Multilinguist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multilinguist)" is a synonym for this.

Answer (score 5):

"**Bilingual**" describes someone who is versatile in two languages. If you want to describe someone who has mastered multiple languages, you could call them a "**polyglot**", although this is properly "someone who speaks 5 or more languages." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(disambiguation))

Also relevant is the word "**biliterate**," simply meaning "able to read and write two different languages." (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biliterate) That conversation was had here: [What word means "the ability to read more than one form of writing"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61769/what-word-means-the-ability-to-read-more-than-one-form-of-writing)